# real time clock puzzle with new rasbian jessie

Tags: rtc

I have been trying to install a RTC on my raspberry pi 2 (running Raspbian Jessie lite 2015-11-21) and I run into the following problem that puzzles me:

1. I set the correct time on the hardware clock and shut down the pi.
2. I unplug the ethernet cable so that the pi is off the internet.
3. I turn on again after about 7/8 minutes and check date and hwclock -r: and here is what I get:

   - Date gives me the correct time (and so does /var/log/syslog). --> so the RTC has done its job.
   - But hwclock -r gives me the wrong time!
     So it seems hwclock is overwritten by something at boot, after it has passed the time correctly to the system.

And of course if I reboot a second time, then date becomes wrong.

[image: Screen shot]

Anyone has an idea of how to fix this?

Here are the current config files. I started without changing config.txt and hwclock-set, and the result was the same:

sudo nano /boot/config.txt: added at the end:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc
```

/lib/udev/hwclock-set: commented out:

```
#if [ -e /run/systemd/system ] ; then
#    exit 0
#fi
```

/etc/modules

```
i2c-bcm2708
i2c-dev
rtc-ds1307
```

and /etc/rc.local

```
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
sudo hwclock -s
```

The RTC model: 
http://thepihut.com/products/mini-rtc-module-for-raspberry-pi?variant=758601217

Comment: Can you paste the configuration files in your answer, please?

Comment: The link you quoted is old, and relates to a previous OS. Tell us WHAT YOU HAVE DONE. We can only guess otherwise.

Comment: I have added the config files, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you should need to do is to add the following line to `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
```

Inserting commands into `init.d` or attempting to load modules is unecessary (and may interfere with normal operation). `Device Tree` should do all this automatically.

You can use ds1307 if you actually have one (the device you linked uses DS3231)

You can turn off `fake-hwclock` if you want, but it should not be necessary.
If you do want to do this you should use the `systemd` command

```
systemctl stop fake-hwclock.service
```

Comment: It's funny you mention the driver is not the same, I hadn't noticed. In their tutorial they talk about ds1307 only. http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: I tried what you said, removing all the RTC config form /etc/ and adding ds3231 after dtoverlay=i2c-rtc and it works fine. Hopefully this is the end of the story..

Comment: one question though, in Dmesg, I get the line: [    4.936860] rtc-ds1307 1-0068: rtc core: registered ds3231 as rtc0 with do I get rtc-ds1307 there?

Comment: I also get the message `rtc-ds1307 1-0068: rtc core: registered ds3231 as rtc0`. I don't know what it means. The ds1307 and ds3231 are very similar chips (at least the internal registers which hold time) so I suspect they are sharing a common driver.

Comment: I left my pi to sleep for about half a day and when I plugged it again, the time got reset to 1 jan 1970. Dmesg: `rtc-ds1307 1-0068: SET TIME!
 rtc-ds1307 1-0068: rtc core: registered ds3231 as rtc0` Do you think it's a pb with the clock this time?

Comment: it seems it's a problem with the RTC super-capacitor running out of charge this time.

Comment: @Clémentine The module I use has a Lithium battery. If `fake-hwclock` is running it (hopefully) will set time to last used until `NTP` takes over. I have only tested with RTC disconnected.

Comment: As of 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie, this no longer works. The RTC can be accessed with the `hwclock` command, but it seems not to be used by systemd. Could you please update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-rc.d fake-hwclock disable S 6
```

...And reboot. See `man fake-hwclock`. This is enabled by default on current versions of Raspbian.

Comment: it seems it has solved my problem!

Comment: @Clémentine It made your problem go away. You should set the correct overlay in `/boot/config.txt` and not modify `/etc/rc.local`. You are mixing 2 different incompatible methods. My setup (with `fake-hwclock`) works properly (even if the RTC is missing). The device you linked uses `DS3231` so you are not using the correct driver.

Comment: It turns out it hasn't solved my problem fully in fact.. From time to time (and i'm not sure yet when..) the hwclock is reset at boot to 1 jan 1970. I will investigate further and post an update.

Comment: Tried this, and found my Raspberry in 1970.