# Raspberry Pi 3 + DS3231 RTC

Tags: pi-3, i2c, rtc

I have done almost everything from numerous tutorials to get the RTC to work, but when I run `sudo hwclock -r`, i still get the following error.

> hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
>   hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for
>   an access method.

My sudo i2cdetect -y 1 is detecting the RTC DS3231 as below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

EDIT: What I have done till now

Connected the RTC to the RasPi 3.
Enabled i2c in sudo raspi-config

My /etc/modules is now

```
snd-bcm2835
i2c-bcm2835
i2c-bcm2708
i2c-dev
rtc-ds1307
```

Added the following lines to /boot/config.txt

```
# Support for rtc ds3231
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
device_tree=
```

My /etc/rc.local has the following lines

```
echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
hwclock -s
```

But i do get an INVALID ARGUMENT ERROR when i run `sudo echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device`.

At the end, sudo hwclock or hwclock gives the error : `hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method. hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.`

Can somebody suggest me on a fix for this.

EDIT:

Tried the fix suggested on a fresh install of NOOBS v1.9.2 after sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Same issue remain.[image]

ADDED on 03.Oct.2016

As per inputs from joan and Milliways,
I have added `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` only, and got the hwclock to give date and time, bu the problem is that hwclock runs like internal clock now, it doesn't keep time across reboots.

Any inputs?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the details of what you have done.  Please don't point to a tutorial, give the salient details.

Comment: @joan: Added the details requested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [real time clock puzzle with new rasbian jessie](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/real-time-clock-puzzle-with-new-rasbian-jessie)

Comment: @Milliways: But there, he is getting a response with sudo hwclock. Here, I am not.

Comment: The real problem is you followed a number of (probably uninformed) tutorials - which you have not detailed, so we can't guess what. Undo all of that (or restore image before it was modified) and apply the single line solution. You are getting no response because you have disabled Device Tree. @joan is correct, but this is just a variant of the question, complicated because you have done lots of other "stuff".

Comment: I just connected up a 3231 and it works fine with the `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231=1` line. `sudo hwclock -r` gave Thu 29 Sep 2016 11:48:27 BST  -0.607987 seconds.  `dmesg|grep rtc` gave [4.791545] rtc-ds1307 1-0068: SET TIME! [4.793978] rtc-ds1307 1-0068: rtc core: registered ds3231 as rtc0.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs: joan and Milliways. Both of you are correct. I have tried too many tutorials one after the other, and that is complicating my situaiton.

Due to power interruption, the device now blinks GREEN LED once on boot, and I think i have to reload the SD Card. I will correct that, and test with the oneline solution, and give an update by tomorrow. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Performed a fresh install of NOOBS v1.9.2 and then did a sudo apt-get update && dist-upgrade.

Then added just dtparam=i2c_arm=on  dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231 to /boot/config.txt.

Same error continues. hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method. hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.

Comment: What does `i2cdetect -y 1` report?

Comment: It shows below:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

Answer (score 3):

You should be using device tree now.

I suggest the following changes.

Remove the following lines from `/etc/modules'

```
snd-bcm2835
i2c-bcm2835
i2c-bcm2708
rtc-ds1307
```

I.e. `/etc/modules` should only contain

```
i2c-dev
```

Remove the following line from `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
hwclock -s
```

**I'm not sure if `hwclock -s` is needed or not.**

Remove the following lines from `/boot/config.txt`

```
# Support for rtc ds3231
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
dtparam=i2c1=on
device_tree=
```

I.e. of those lines only leave

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
```

See `/boot/overlays/README` for general information.

Comment: The “hwclock -s” added to “rc.local” sets the system time from the RTC module

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo hwclock -r
sudo hwclock -w
```

Comment: Kindly provide a brief outline of what these commands do. :)

Comment: Also, explain how this addresses the problem.

Comment: On Raspberry Pi 3, sudo hwclock -r says
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --verbose option to see the details of our search for an access method.